JEEContext in DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler with cas v6.6.15
I'm using cas-overlay-template 6.6.15 with pac4j 5.4.6 and I'm having dependency issues implementing the DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler class. The class extends AbstractPac4jAuthenticationHandler, I'm doing it this way because I'm relying on a previous cas implementation (v6.3.7.4).
When doing:
import org.pac4j.core.context.JEEContext;
import org.pac4j.core.context.session.SessionStore;
I get an error that the import does not resolve, however the JEEContext class exists and the SessionStore interface also exists
The class in question is the following:

import org.apereo.cas.authentication.AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult;
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.Credential;
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.PreventedException;
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.PrincipalFactory;
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.Service;
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.provision.DelegatedClientUserProfileProvisioner;
import org.apereo.cas.integration.pac4j.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPac4jAuthenticationHandler;
import org.apereo.cas.services.ServicesManager;
import org.pac4j.core.client.Clients;
import org.pac4j.core.context.session.SessionStore;
import org.pac4j.core.context.JEEContext;
import org.pac4j.core.context.session.SessionStore;

public class DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractPac4jAuthenticationHandler {

    private final Clients clients;
    private final DelegatedClientUserProfileProvisioner profileProvisioner;
    private final SessionStore<JEEContext> sessionStore;

    protected DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler(String name, ServicesManager servicesManager,
            PrincipalFactory principalFactory, Integer order, SessionStore sessionStore) {
        super(name, servicesManager, principalFactory, order, sessionStore);
        //TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult doAuthentication(Credential credential, Service service)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, PreventedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unimplemented method 'doAuthentication'");
    }
    
}

Maybe in version 6.6.15 you have to extend another class or maybe you have to use something other than JEEContext?

CAS 6.6.15 depends on pac4j v5.4.6.
It's org.pac4j.jee.context.JEEContext from the pac4j-javaee dependency and org.pac4j.core.context.session.SessionStore from the pac4j-core dependency.
